# RAID10 health deteriorating

Tags: raid, mdadm

**Update**: I have added output from `smartctl` short tests for all drives. One seems to be generating errors, but overall tests have passed.

A few days ago I set up a fresh software RAID10 (mdadm) using 4 4TB hard drives.
According to the output from `mdadm -d` and `cat /proc/mdstat`, all RAID devices are functioning properly. However, straight away, I noticed that operations such as creating a directory would take a few seconds around half of the time.

Resyncing is also taking an incredibly long time (up and running since 25th of October, but only 10% synced).

And lastly, since today, I have had issues accessing the mounted drive array. When using `cd` the shell hangs once I use tab to autocomplete the path past the drive's root directory. When using `df -h` on a remote host that mounts the RAID array as a Samba share, I get the message 'Host is down' or 'Resource temporarily unavailable' after a minute or two.

```
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon Oct 25 20:18:15 2021
        Raid Level : raid10
        Array Size : 7813769216 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 3906884608 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Fri Oct 29 05:24:29 2021
             State : active, resyncing
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : near=2
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

     Resync Status : 10% complete

              Name : i7-harvester:1  (local to host i7-harvester)
              UUID : eb089c26:4b9b1dc7:7d9481f9:69e5a3df
            Events : 42562

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       33        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdc1
       2       8       49        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdd1
       3       8       65        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sde1
```

(note the speed reported by `mdstat` used to be around 3000k, but has since today decreased to 3K/sec)

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid10 sde1[3] sdd1[2] sdc1[1] sdb1[0]
      7813769216 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      [==>..................]  resync = 10.7% (837141440/7813769216) finish=33547280.3min speed=3K/sec
      bitmap: 53/59 pages [212KB], 65536KB chunk
```

`df` on remote system

```
$ df -h
df: /mnt/data: Resource temporarily unavailable
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        59G   13G   44G  22% /
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  202M  1.7G  11% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   49M  204M  20% /boot
/dev/sda1       1.8T  131G  1.6T   8% /mnt/nas
```

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-38-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi/HGST Ultrastar 7K4000
Device Model:     HGST HUS724040ALA640
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 22bf6d532
Add. Product Id:  DELL(tm)
Firmware Version: MFAOAB50
User Capacity:    4.000.787.030.016 bytes [4,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Oct 30 09:11:05 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (   24) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 533) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0004   138   138   000    Old_age   Offline      -       75
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   127   127   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       609 (Average 607)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0004   140   140   000    Old_age   Offline      -       26
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       62287
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1473
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1473
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   157   157   000    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 18/47)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       265905350843
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1599707339787

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     62275         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     61911         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        12         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%        12         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-38-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi/HGST Ultrastar 7K4000
Device Model:     HGST HUS724040ALA640
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 23dc4c637
Add. Product Id:  DELL(tm)
Firmware Version: MFAOAB50
User Capacity:    4.000.787.030.016 bytes [4,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Oct 30 09:13:13 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (   24) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 553) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0004   139   139   000    Old_age   Offline      -       73
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   125   125   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       624 (Average 611)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0004   138   138   000    Old_age   Offline      -       27
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       50333
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       380
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       380
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   162   162   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Min/Max 20/46)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       186666664018
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1482419943771

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     50321         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     49927         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        11         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%        11         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-38-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2b6822d7f
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    4.000.787.030.016 bytes [4,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Oct 30 09:14:05 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (51720) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 517) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x703d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   209   177   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       6508
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2532
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   060   060   000    Old_age   Always       -       29367
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       15
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   196   196   000    Old_age   Always       -       14465
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   115   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 2
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 28742 hours (1197 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  10 51 10 e0 32 1e e0  Error: IDNF at LBA = 0x001e32e0 = 1979104

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ca 00 10 e0 32 1e e0 08   3d+00:35:32.256  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 08 00 29 0c e0 08   3d+00:35:32.245  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 08 c0 0f 19 e0 08   3d+00:35:32.234  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 40 a8 44 1f e0 08   3d+00:35:32.175  WRITE DMA

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 28670 hours (1194 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  10 51 08 80 06 4c e0  Error: IDNF at LBA = 0x004c0680 = 4982400

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ca 00 08 80 06 4c e0 08  13d+13:29:55.786  WRITE DMA
  b0 d0 01 00 4f c2 00 08  13d+13:29:47.191  SMART READ DATA
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 08  13d+13:29:47.191  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     29354         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sde
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-38-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Desktop HDD.15
Device Model:     ST4000DM000-1F2168
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 05070b3a5
Firmware Version: CC52
User Capacity:    4.000.787.030.016 bytes [4,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5900 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Oct 30 09:15:01 2021 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  623) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 540) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x1085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   111   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       33492856
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   093   091   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       256
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   067   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       5757534
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       7873
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       131
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   087   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       13
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   099   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       1002 1042 1081
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   066   045   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 34 (Min/Max 25/36)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       101
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       21749
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   034   055   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (0 1 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   199   194   000    Old_age   Always       -       790247
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1330h+40m+55.940s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       39004091013
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       16225042845

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7861         -
# 2  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%      7762         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I'm at a loss on how to troubleshoot or fix (I'm new to RAIDs), so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: HYTTIONOA has seemed to fix the slow re-sync at least. Now looking at about 10 hours for a full resync. Will update if the other issues seem resolved as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot of my system fixed all symptoms.